# setNeedsDisplay not working after adding subviews

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, addsubview, setneedsdisplay

I added about 500 views to my viewController.view.
This action took about 5 seconds on target.
Now I want the screen to refresh after each subview I'm adding, so the user will see them appears one by one on screen.

I tried this in my viewController:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    for(int i=0; i<500; i++)
    {
        //...Create aView
        [self.view addsubview:aView];
        [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}
```

I run it and nothing happened for 5 seconds then all views appeared at once.
I made sure that [self.view setNeedsDisplay] called from the main thread context.

Any idea how to make those subviews appear one by one?

Comment: You should probably read the documentation for `setNeedsDisplay`. It's _doesn't_ force a redraw, nor should it.

Comment: Depending on what visual effect you are trying to do, timers, run loops, and animations are other good topics to research.

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple solution. I added a new property to my viewController - 'subviewsCount' witch was initialised to 500. then called the following method from viewDidLoad:

```
-(void) addSubviewsToMotherView
{
    self.subviewsCount -=1;
    if (self.subviewsCount >= 0)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.0
                              delay:0.0
                            options:UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews
                         animations:^{
                             [self methodToAddSubview];
                         }
                         completion:^(BOOL finished){
                             [self addSubviewsToMotherView];
                         }
         ];

    }
}
```